# Delete Credential Manager Stored Credentials at once

Tags: cmd, command, prompt

I was looking for a more efficient way to delete all credentials stored in Credential Manager without having to delete credentials one by one. After few hours of browsing, I have finally stumbled upon this command prompt string that does exactly what I need:

```
for /F "tokens=1,2 delims= " %G in ('cmdkey /list ^| findstr Target') do  cmdkey /delete %H
```

Since my knowledge of this syntax is quite limited, I would like to know what each of its section actually means. I already know what **cmdkey /list, findstr** and **cmdkey /delete** do but I am not sure about the rest.

Moreover, I would like to know how to make exceptions. For instance, in this case the line deletes all the strings that have a target as displayed in cmdkey list:
[cmdkey.exe /list example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iX9Xz.png)
What if I want to make an exception and delete only some credentials but not other? Could I do that using the Type value instead of the Target value, for instance by asking the command prompt to delete only the Generic type credentials and not the Generic Certificate and the Domain Password type credentials?

Thanks in advance for your help.

KR,
Andy

Answer (score 0):

When using the string "**for /F "tokens=1,2 delims= " %G in ('cmdkey /list ^| findstr Target') do  cmdkey /delete %H**", I keep getting "**CMDKEY: Element not found.**"

Therefore I scripted a quite primitive workaround since I do not know batch syntax so well. The script below puts together all the lines that have to be run in cmd to delete the corresponding CM keys. The last command in the script, invokes the file with all the lines. You have to just copy/paste them in a cmd and hit enter and it removes most of them:

```
$cachedCredentials = cmdkey /list
$CMCredentialsTxt = "C:\temp\CMCredentials.txt"
$cachedCredentials | Out-File $CMCredentialsTxt
(Get-Content $CMCredentialsTxt) | ? {$_.trim() -ne "" } | Set-Content $CMCredentialsTxt
(Get-Content $CMCredentialsTxt).Trim() | Set-Content $CMCredentialsTxt
(Get-Content $CMCredentialsTxt).Replace("Currently stored credentials:","") | Set-Content $CMCredentialsTxt
(Get-Content $CMCredentialsTxt).Replace("Type: Generic", "") | Set-Content $CMCredentialsTxt
(Get-Content $CMCredentialsTxt).Replace("User: App Info","") | Set-Content $CMCredentialsTxt
(Get-Content $CMCredentialsTxt).Replace("Local machine persistence","") | Set-Content $CMCredentialsTxt
(Get-Content $CMCredentialsTxt).Replace("Target: ","") | Set-Content $CMCredentialsTxt
(Get-Content $CMCredentialsTxt).Replace("User: <Certificate>","") | Set-Content $CMCredentialsTxt
(Get-Content $CMCredentialsTxt).Replace("Certificate","") | Set-Content $CMCredentialsTxt
(Get-Content $CMCredentialsTxt).Replace("User: User DT","") | Set-Content $CMCredentialsTxt
(Get-Content $CMCredentialsTxt).Replace("User: User OS Info","") | Set-Content $CMCredentialsTxt
(Get-Content $CMCredentialsTxt) | ? {$_.trim() -ne "" } | Set-Content $CMCredentialsTxt
$cleanTargets = Get-Content $CMCredentialsTxt
Remove-Item $CMCredentialsTxt
forEach ($cleanTarget in $cleanTargets){"cmdkey /delete:" + $cleanTarget | Out-File $CMCredentialsTxt -Append}
Invoke-Item $CMCredentialsTxt
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a very old post, but I wanted to show how I modified your first command to work with names that contain spaces and colons.

```
for /F "tokens=1,* delims= " %G in ('cmdkey /list ^| findstr Target') do  cmdkey /delete:"%H"
```

Replacing the 2 with a * in tokens returns the rest of the line instead of just the next token (space delimited in this case)

Wrapping the delete parameter for cmdkey should ensure the correct entry is deleted.